# Why is const unnecessary in function declarations in header files for parameters passed by value?

Tags: c, pointers, constants, header-files

I was recently reading about the usage of `const` keyword as function arguments in C and the way to use that has been mentioned in [When and for what purposes should the `const` keyword be used in C for variables](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/204500/when-and-for-what-purposes-should-the-const-keyword-be-used-in-c-for-variables) and been accepted as correct answer. In this post, one point mentions that

> Never use `const` in a function prototype for a parameter passed by
>   value. It has no meaning and is hence just 'noise'.

I used this way and it works for me but I am not sure why that is a **noise** for parameters passed by value and yet not a noise for the parameters passed by reference (more aptly the pointer values in C as there is not concept of `pass by value` and `pass by reference` in C). So, by this explanation when I pass a pointer as a function argument and use a `const` keyword; I have to do this for both the declaration in the header file and the definition in the C file but I need not use the `const` keyword for a non-pointer argument in the declaration (header file) and only use it while defining the function in the C file.

Any explanations?

Comment: Since you are passing by value, changing the value has no actual effect. Calling it a const doesn't really do much.

Comment: It doesn't matter the slightest to the calling code whether `double sqrt(double)` or `double sqrt(const double)` is used.  If the user has: `double x = 3.14; double y = sqrt(x);`, the `sqrt()` function cannot modify the variable `x` regardless of the presence or absence of the `const` (and a `const` in the return type would be equally pointless).  It does matter with pointers, though.  If you had `char *fgets(const char *buffer, size_t buflen, FILE *fp);`, it promises not to modify the data that `buffer` points at, which renders it impotent as an input function — it has to modify the buffer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The statement you quote is a bit misleading, because in C, *all* arguments are passed by value.<sup>*</sup>  I suppose it is trying to distinguish between the arguments themselves and, for the special case of arguments that are pointers, their referents.

In any event, the point is that `const`-qualifying a function parameter in the function declaration conveys no information whatever to callers.  Regardless of such qualification, the function cannot modify the caller's copy of any argument anyway, because arguments are *passed by value*.

<sup>*</sup>Note, however, that arrays are never passed at all.  In function call expressions, as in most contexts, array values "decay" to pointers, and those pointers are passed by value.  This produces an effect similar, but not identical, to what you would have if arrays were passed by reference.

Comment: How about in the case of something like `char const * str` in a function prototype's parameters (say, in a header file)?

Comment: @user129393192, that would not be a case of a `const`-qualified function parameter.  `const char *`  is a *non*-`const` pointer to a `const char`.

Comment: Got it. So `const`-qualification of the object that is passed in is useless unless used to double-check correctness / self-documentation, is this correct?

Comment: @user129393192, neither the question nor this answer says anything about double-checking correctness or self-documentation.  The quotation the question asks about calls `const`-qualification of function parameters nothing but noise, and I tend to agree.

Comment: I was referring to the definition, but I agree with you on the prototype

Answer (score 6):

It's the rule. If in the *declaration* of a function, you don't mark your parameters `const`, you *can* mark them `const` in the *definition*.

Some folk like to mark as many parameters `const` as possible in the definition since it can guard against unintentional modification of the function parameters; which could introduce bugs. Personally I don't do this but plenty of houses (including a large bank headquartered in Scotland) insist on the style.

Comment: LSNED about motivations for using `void foo(const int x) { ...}`

Answer (score 1):

Posting this here because I wrote it for a code review and figured it was worth preserving:

Adding const to a value-type parameter in the function *declaration* is useless. The caller won't care whether the parameter is modified or not because the caller's data won't be affected in any way. The parameter is a separate object than the argument that was passed in, constructed by copy [or by move for rvalue arguments into move-constructible parameters (since C++11)].

Adding const to a value-type parameter in the function *definition* marks the separate, function-local object as const. This is essentially the same as marking a local variable 'const', and value-type parameters should usually be treated as local variables when determining whether the value-type should be const.

The C & C++ standards demand that compilers & linkers be smart enough to match the following declaration with its definition:

```
// Declaration
void Foo(int bar);

// Definition
void Foo(const int bar){
 printf("%i", bar);
}
```